# Pine script error "line 27: Syntax error at input 'i'."

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5

I tried everything but it still gives me this error: "**line 27: Syntax error at input 'i'.**" It seems there are no indentation issues either.

Help please. Thank you in advance.

'''

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © VaheHV

//@version=5
strategy("Momentum Signal", overlay=true)

ema12 = ta.ema(close, 12)
ema26 = ta.ema(close, 26)
ema9 = ta.ema(close, 9)
macdLine = ema12 - ema26
macdSignal = ta.ema(macdLine, 9)

crossover = ta.crossover(macdLine, macdSignal)
crossunder = ta.crossunder(macdLine, macdSignal)

if crossover and macdLine < 0 and macdSignal < 0 and close > ta.ema(close, 200)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if crossunder and macdLine > 0 and macdSignal > 0 and close < ta.ema(close, 200)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    
float[] longStopLoss = na
float[] longTakeProfit = na
float[] shortStopLoss = na
float[] shortTakeProfit = na

if strategy.opentrades != 0
    for i = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
        if strategy.position_size > 0
            array.push(longStopLoss, ta.lowest(low, 15))
            array.push(longTakeProfit, (1.5*(strategy.opentrades.entry_price(i) - longStopLoss[i]) + strategy.opentrades.entry_price(i)))
            strategy.exit("LongClose", profit = longTakeProfit[i] * 100, loss = longStopLoss[i] * 100)
        else if strategy.position_size < 0
            array.push(shortStopLoss, ta.highest(high, 15))
            array.push(shortTakeProfit, (strategy.opentrades.entry_price(i) - 1.5*(shortStopLoss[i] - strategy.opentrades.entry_price(i)))
            strategy.exit("ShortClose", profit = shortTakeProfit[i] * 100, loss = shortStopLoss[i] * 100)
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

`[]` in `pinescript` is called [history reference operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator). It is used to access historical data of a variable.

You don't use `[]` to access array elements. Instead, you should use `array.get()` function for that.

Also, below line is missing one closing parentheses. So, check this line in my example.

```
array.push(shortTakeProfit, (strategy.opentrades.entry_price(i) - 1.5*(shortStopLoss[i] - strategy.opentrades.entry_price(i)))
```

This should work:

```
if strategy.opentrades != 0
    for i = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
        if strategy.position_size > 0
            array.push(longStopLoss, ta.lowest(low, 15))
            array.push(longTakeProfit, (1.5*(strategy.opentrades.entry_price(i) - array.get(longStopLoss, i)) + strategy.opentrades.entry_price(i)))
            strategy.exit("LongClose", profit = array.get(longTakeProfit, i) * 100, loss = array.get(longStopLoss, i) * 100)
        else if strategy.position_size < 0
            array.push(shortStopLoss, ta.highest(high, 15))
            array.push(shortTakeProfit, (strategy.opentrades.entry_price(i) - 1.5*(array.get(shortStopLoss, i) - strategy.opentrades.entry_price(i))))
            strategy.exit("ShortClose", profit = array.get(shortTakeProfit, i) * 100, loss = array.get(shortStopLoss, i) * 100)
```